# In MVC, How can I set a value for total by summing the values in textfields and then save to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I feel like the answer is staring me in the face... I have a create controller where on POST I set some values so they will save correctly. These work fine. When I add math it isn't giving me the results I expected. I want to set the value for Total to the sum of several other int fields instead of having to enter it myself. However, when I debug the values are passed and the Total remains null. I need card.Cards.TotalManaCost to have a value so I can save it along with all the other fields to my database. Any Advice?

```
card.Cards.TotalManaCost = card.Cards.RedManaCost + card.Cards.GreenManaCost + 
card.Cards.WhiteManaCost + card.Cards.BlueManaCost + card.Cards.BlackManaCost;
```

**EDIT**
The Card Model is quite long but that is where the TotalManaCost, RedManaCost, GreenManaCost, etc. are. I have pasted the full Create Post action and the View Model along with a view snippet. :)

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(int[] SelectedAbilities, int SelectedRarities, int SelectedMainTypes, int SelectedSubTypes, int SelectedCardSets, CreateCardViewModel card)

        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    card.Cards.MainTypeID = card.SelectedMainTypes;
                    card.Cards.CardSetID = card.SelectedCardSets;
                    card.Cards.SubTypeID = card.SelectedSubTypes;
                    card.Cards.RarityID = card.SelectedRarities;
                    card.Cards.TotalManaCost = card.Cards.RedManaCost + card.Cards.GreenManaCost + 
                    card.Cards.WhiteManaCost + card.Cards.BlueManaCost + card.Cards.BlackManaCost;


                    //IMAGE PATH AND SAVE
                    if (card.ImageUpload != null)
                    {
                        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images\\");
                        if (card.Cards.Foil == true)
                        {
                            string foil = "foil";
                            savedFileName = savedFileName + card.Cards.Title + card.Cards.CardSetID + foil + ".jpg";
                            card.ImageUpload.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                            card.Cards.ImageUrl = "\\Images\\" + card.Cards.Title + card.Cards.CardSetID + foil + ".jpg";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            savedFileName = savedFileName + card.Cards.Title + card.Cards.CardSetID + ".jpg";
                            card.ImageUpload.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                            card.Cards.ImageUrl = "\\Images\\" + card.Cards.Title + card.Cards.CardSetID + ".jpg";
                        }
                        //END IMAGE
                    }



                    db.Cards.Add(card.Cards);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    if (SelectedAbilities != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var items in card.SelectedAbilities)
                        {
                            var obj = new CardAbility() { AbilityID = items, CardID = card.Cards.CardID };
                            db.CardAbilities.Add(obj);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }


                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            ViewBag.RarityID = new SelectList(db.Rarities, "RarityID", "Title", card.Cards.RarityID);
            ViewBag.MainTypeID = new SelectList(db.MainTypes, "MainTypeID", "Title", card.Cards.MainTypeID);
            ViewBag.CardSetID = new SelectList(db.CardSets, "CardSetID", "Title", card.Cards.CardSetID);
            ViewBag.SubTypeID = new SelectList(db.SubTypes, "SubTypeID", "Title", card.Cards.SubTypeID);
            ViewBag.Abilities = new MultiSelectList(db.Abilities, "AbilityID", "Title");
            return View(card);
        }
```

Create View Model

```
 public class CreateCardViewModel
    {
        //private Card card;


        public Card Cards { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
        //public IList<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }
        //public int LinkedCard { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Abilities { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedAbilities { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rarities { get; set; }
        public int SelectedRarities { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MainTypes { get; set; }
        public int SelectedMainTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubTypes { get; set; }
        public int SelectedSubTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectList> CardSets { get; set; }
        public int SelectedCardSets { get; set; }
        public Rarity Rarity { get; set; } 
        public MainType MainType { get; set; }
        public SubType SubType { get; set; }
        public CardSet CardSet { get; set; }

        public CreateCardViewModel() { }
        public CreateCardViewModel(Card card)
        {
            Cards = card;

        }


    }
```

View Snippet

```
<div class="editor-field">

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost, new {style = "width:20px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost)
        </div>
```

Comment: We need to see more code than this.  Can you post the whole action method?  Likewise, it would help to see the View (snippet) and any models/view models involved.

Comment: Please add the Card object too.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy need to save TotalManaCost to the DB then you need a dedicated table for it.

But I don't see a reason for it. Just add a property that looks exactly like one of your mana-properties (whatever this looks like) but returns the sum of all mana.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Cards mapping in EF doesn't map TotalManaCost. That would create the situation you are seeing.

But if I could recommend a different approach...

Instead of saving the total mana cost in the database, why not just calculate it when needed? In the Cards object, this would look like:

```
public int TotalManaCost
{
    get 
    {
        return RedManaCost + GreenManaCost + BlueManaCost + WhiteManaCost + BlackManaCost;
    }
}
```

That will allow you to use the property whenever you need it without having to store it in the database. Plus, all of this will be invisible to the consumer of the data.

Note: You need to tell EF not to map this property. With Code First, that's done through the [NotMapped] attribute on this property. If you forget this, EF will throw an exception when it tries to populate the TotalManaCost property from the database.

Comment: I need it to save to the database because it is used in the search for cards section. If I enter TotalManaCost myself when creating a card it saves to the database fine.

Comment: Are you sure card.Cards.RedManaCost along with all of the others are populated when you calculate the total? Given this new information, the card.Cards object is probably not completely populated when the MVC method is called.